# while configuring ldap over ssl it throws an error quoting "Invalid user ldap."

Tags: ssl, fedora, tls1.2, openldap, fedora-27

I have been trying to configure the ldap over ssl by following the instructions from the site https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_27&p=openldap .

While Implementing the command

`chown ldap. /etc/openldap/certs/server.key /etc/openldap/certs/server.crt /etc/openldap/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

It throws an error saying chown: invalid user: ‘ldap.’

Does anyone have any explantion regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I had my ldap server setup at one machine and I was beating the commands into the other machine. Later I realised, though it's not compulsory, name your remote servers completely different to avoid the confusion.